# Get number of files acted upon by bash commands

Tags: bash, command-line, output

How would I go about getting, as output from an

```
rm -r
```

command on a folder, the number of files it operated on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this (with GNU `rm` at least):

```
rm -rv dir | wc -l
```

The `-v` flag causes `rm` to output lines like this:

```
removed `dir/file'
removed directory: `dir'
```

and `wc -l` counts the lines. As written, the count will included directories removed. You could get rid of those lines with something like `grep -v "^removed directory"` but that will depend on your locale so it might not be totally reliable.